# Method Swizzling not firing correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swizzling

I am following this [article](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to better understand how method swizzling works. I have my main view controller (this is a new project) like this:

```
#import "GLViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (Tracking)

+ (void)load {
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    Class class = [UIViewController class];

    SEL originalSelector = @selector(viewWillAppear:);
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(xxx_viewWillAppear:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

    BOOL didAddMethod =
    class_addMethod(class,
                    originalSelector,
                    method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(class,
                            swizzledSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
});
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

- (void)xxx_viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self xxx_viewWillAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"viewWillAppear: %@", self);
}

@end


@implementation GLViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  NSLog(@"glviewappear");
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If I run this, then it prints glviewappear, and if I remove

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  NSLog(@"glviewappear");
}
```

then it prints  `viewWillAppear: <GLViewController: 0x9d11a90>`. My project needs to be able to fire on both of these methods. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple reason. You are not calling the UIViewController implementation since you are not calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated]`.

Just do:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  NSLog(@"glviewappear");
}
```

### Here is a more detailed explanation

Each method in an Objective C class is nothing more than a simple function, referenced through a pointer saved in a dispatch table: the keys are the selectors, and their associated values are the pointers to each method implementation (the `IMP`).

When you swizzle, you just swap two pointers in the dispatch table, in order to swap the referenced functions. Since the dispatch table is attached to the class, swizzling happens **only** in the class on which you perform it, and not in the subclasses.

In your case, there are 3 different functions in play:
UIViewController has the pointers to the following functions in the dispatch table. These functions get swapped at runtime through swizzling.

- `viewWillAppear:` (now pointing to `xxx_viewWillAppear:` implementation)
- `xxx_viewWillAppear:` (now pointing to `viewWillAppear:` implementation)

GLViewController has another pointer, to its own implementation of `viewWillAppear:`.

If you don't call `super`, you are not accessing the dispatch table of the `UIViewController` class, so you are not invoking the implementation at all.

When you delete your viewWillAppear: method, obviously it works, since the super implementation gets automatically called.

Comment: great answer and explanation. How can I got call in xxx_viewWillAppear without writing   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
in viewWillAppear ?

Comment: @user2906829 the only ways to run xxx_viewWillAppear are: 1) calling super viewWillAppear (that will directly call the swizzled viewWillAppear, and so xxx_viewWillAppear) or 2) removing the whole viewWillAppear method in the subclass, so the super implementation get called directly (and so the swizzled method)